# Using the bitcoind, can I query if funds have been sent to a multisig address?

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature

I would like to query whether funds have been sent to a multi-sig address.

Using the daemon: the address is valid, but listunspent and getreceivedbyaddress don't show the multisig address. I can see a txn, which reports the target address is my multisig address.

I suppose I am asking how do the apis from blockr.io work (e.g. btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/info/...... ) ?

TIA

Comment: Is the multisig address one of your 'watch' addresses? (`bitcoind importaddress <addr>`) Can you try adding it to the watch address list, then run `bitcoind -rescan`?

Comment: Thank-you. I tried that - now I see it in listunspent. Is there a way to rescan without starting the daemon? I want to create many addresses. I will try importing the address before funds are sent - maybe that will work.

Comment: So, if you import the address before you use the address on the network, then you don't need `rescan`.

Comment: Brilliant - it's good when things are thought out properly. Thank-you so much.